# babel-loader + Webpack with both @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-react at the same time

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

Basically, what the title says, does it make sense to use both `preset-env` and `preset-react` on the same WebpPack `rule` when matching a file that contains some jsx.

If it is, what is the correct way to do this (using the latest versions), such as ordering them, and if not, why not?

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, it makes sense

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-webpack-for-react-a36d4cac5060/

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```